# How to filter ng-repeat list on empty string values with an inputfield?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

How can I filter an ng-repeat to show all items where a certain columnfield is an empty string? When I try this by typing nothing in the field it always seem to give the full list (which is expected). I only want to see the person with id 1. How can I adjust the filter that a certain character in the inputfield makes the ng repeat filter on empty fields for the **name** column.

[FiddleJs Example](http://jsfiddle.net/otzz1gLg/)

My view:

```
<div class="panel-heading">
   <h3>Filtered by {{filterValue}}</h3>
   <input ng-change="filter()" ng-model="filterValue"/>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
   <ul class="list-unstyled">
     <li ng-repeat="p in filteredPeople">
       <h4>{{p.name}} ({{p.age}}) id: {{p.id}}</h4>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
    var people = [{
        name: '',
        age: 32,
        id: 1
    }, {
        name: 'Jonny',
        age: 34,
        id: 2
    }, {
        name: 'Blake',
        age: 28,
        id: 3
    }, {
        name: 'David',
        age: 35,
        id: 4
    }];
    
    $scope.filter = function (value) {
     $scope.filteredPeople = $filter('filter')(people, {
        name: $scope.filterValue
     });
    }

    $scope.people = people.slice(0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete your `$scope.filter()` function in the controller and the `ng-change="filter()"` in your view. You should change `var people` array to `$scope.people`. You also need to delete the line `$scope.people = people.slice(0);`.

Create a filter function in your controller to only return people whose `name` property is empty if `$scope.filterValue` is empty:

```
$scope.emptyFilter = function(person) {
    if ($scope.filterValue.length === 0) {
        if (person.name.length === 0) {
            return person;
        }
    } else {
        return person;
    }
};
```

Next, update your `ng-repeat` with the following:

`<li ng-repeat="p in people | filter:emptyFilter | filter:{name: filterValue}">`